# Error 0x800700E0: Access denied when copying files using open with windows explorer

Tags: 2013, open-with-explorer

One of our user receiving error when trying to copy files using **open with windows explorer**. She was able to do it on her old laptop, but on new laptop she is getting error.

The old laptop was having windows 7 and office 2013 whether new laptop has windows 10 and office 2016.

[image]

I have done below checks to resolve the issue, but it didn't helped:

1. I have added the URL in trusted setting
2. Webdav service is also running on her laptop

Is any other settings I need to check?

Comment: Hello P S, i having the same issue with SharePoint Online environment. Previously I was able to move files around in Open with explorer view, but i can't do it any more. I receive the same error. I added the URL to trusted sites, but that din help. Where you successful in resolving this issue? Please suggest.

Comment: Hi Axa, after adding in trusted setting, select automatic logon with current username and password in settings. This may help

Comment: Glad it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Error 0x800700E0: Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the website to your trusted sites list, browse the website, and select the option to log in automatically. I've added the site to the trusted sites list, as well as selected the option to log in automatically.

Regards,
Peter